# Detect changes on NSUserDefaults with suiteName

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I created appGroups and did set up a `NSUserDefaults` using that group. I have a observer for which is not triggered when the value is changed.

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.daniesy.text")!            
defaults.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "temp", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
defaults.setBool(!defaults.boolForKey("temp"), forKey: "temp")
defaults.synchronize()

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    println("changed")
}
```

However if i ignore the appGroup and use `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()` it works as expected.
Any idea why it's not working?

Comment: yes, weird... observer for forKeyPath it's not working with suiteName; the only solution is to observer "globally" all the NSUserDefault:        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "defaultsChanged_selector", name: NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification, object: nil)

Comment: Would this work when changing nsuser defaults externally? Like from a widget or other app?

Comment: It's working, you can check this example also - http://www.glimsoft.com/06/28/ios-8-today-extension-tutorial/  (PS Hello Cluj! :D )

Comment: The sharing of data works indeed, i need the observer to work. Hello Bucuresti :D :))

Comment: I have tested the above code (Today Extension) and the observer it's working properly (at least for the moment iOS 8.1)

Comment: I'm on iOS 8.1 also. This is strange.

Comment: just a moment... to check again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63797/discussion-between-tonymkenu-and-dnu-mihai-florian).

Comment: Hopes there is a solution for it.

Comment: Nope didn't find a suitable one

Comment: As of the release of iOS 10 and macOS 10.12, the Foundation release notes mention...
Key-Value Observing and NSUserDefaults - In previous releases, KVO could only be used on the instance of NSUserDefaults returned by the +standardUserDefaults method.... These limitations have both been corrected.

Answer (score 4):

#### Foundation Release Notes for macOS 10.12 and iOS 10

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/Miscellaneous/RN-Foundation-OSX10.12/index.html

> #### Key-Value Observing and NSUserDefaults
>
> In previous releases, KVO could only be used on the instance of NSUserDefaults returned by the +standardUserDefaults method. Additionally, changes from other processes (such as defaults(1), extensions, or other apps in an app group) were ignored by KVO. These limitations have both been corrected. Changes from other processes will be delivered asynchronously on the main queue, and ignore NSKeyValueObservingOptionPrior.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding suitename instead of initializing. Set up an App Group if you want to share the data

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.addSuiteNamed("group.daniesy.text")
defaults.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "temp", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
defaults.setBool(!defaults.boolForKey("temp"), forKey: "temp")
defaults.synchronize()

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    println("changed")
}
```